# How to fix the position of a tooltip relative to textbox in HTML?

Tags: html, css, scroll, tooltip

A tool-tip is shown when I click inside of a text-box and the tool-tip disappears when I exit the text-box using the following JavaScript codes and CSS. The problem is the scrolling of the page. The position of tool-tip changes equal to the scrolling value. How can I fix the the position of a tool-tip relative to text-box in HTML?

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .tooltip {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        width: 450px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        color: red;
        background-color: #ffffe6;
        font-family: 'B Yekan';
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1px;
        border: solid 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tooltip_show(tooltipId, inputId) {
        var inputField = document.getElementById(inputId);
        var rectObject = inputField.getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = rectObject.top, left = rectObject.left;
        var it = document.getElementById(tooltipId);
        it.style.left = (left - it.offsetWidth / 2 + inputField.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
        it.style.top = (top + inputField.offsetHeight + 5) + 'px';
        var a = inputField.scrollTop;
        it.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    function tooltip_hide(tooltipId) {
        var it = document.getElementById(tooltipId);
        it.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: shared html code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This tooltip created with pure css.

```css
body {
  height:800px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: orange;
  top: -30px;
  left: 60px;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: '\25bc';
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  color: #000;

}

.txt:focus + .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 TextBox : <input type="text" class="txt">
 <div class="tooltip">This is TextBox</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply and professional solution. I check the code and it works well. How can I determine the position of text-box  in order to set the top and left values for tool-tip in CSS.

Comment: If your text-boxs have fixed place , you can test left and top and get Perfect left and top.

Comment: if my post help you give me upvote and mark it,please.

Answer (score 0):

Please use position absolute instead of fixed.

Apart from the above, be careful with your solution, because if you change the coordinates of the textbox itself, the tooltip will not move together.

A better solution would be to create a wrapper element, make it position relative, and use position absolute on the tooltip. This way, if you move the wrapper around, the tooltip will move with it.

Comment: How can I create a wrapper element?

Comment: The other answer contains a wrapper element, it is the div with class container. Wrapper is any element that wraps around what we want to srtyle.

Comment: but in some cases the wrapper element set overflow hidden then tooltip can not display, I'm searching a solution for this problem.